# node js error "No input sources specified"

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity

I have written a simple class in Solidity and getting the following error:

```
$ node compile.js
{ errors: [ 'No input sources specified.' ], sourceList: [] }
$ ls
compile.js  contracts/  node_modules/  package-lock.json  package.json
$ ls contracts/
Inbox.sol
```

My compile.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(solc, 1));
```

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `console.log(solc.compile(solc, 1));`

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

console.log(solc.compile(source, 1)); // Edit
```

Comment: that's a great catch, thank you so much for pointing it out! :)